# IIS 7 rewrite regex equivalent of .htaccess rules

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iis-7

I have some rules in .htaccess and I'm trying to implement them in the new IIS7 rewrite module area .

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*(mp3|m4a|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|bmp|pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx|)$

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]

 RewriteRule . - [R=403,L]
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1):

It is suprisingly similar:

```xml
<rule name="BlockUnauthorized">
  <match url="."/>
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" type="Pattern"
         pattern="^.*(mp3|m4a|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|bmp|pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx|)$" />
    <add input="{HTTP_COOKIE}" type="Pattern"
         pattern="^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403"
          statusReason="You need to log in, fool!" 
          statusDescription="You need to log in, fool!" />
</rule>
```

The rules where translated directly, so any issues you had on your original rules, would probably appear here too.

---

One issue is the first pattern on `REQUEST_FILENAME`; It ends with `|)` which makes the whole group optional. Since `.*` would match anything, it is equivalent to `^.*$`. That is, it will always match any url.

If you just want to match files ending with those extensions, you could use:

```
<match url="." isFile="true"/>
...
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" type="Pattern"
     pattern="\.(mp3|m4a|jpeg|jpg|gif|png|bmp|pdf|doc|docx|ppt|pptx)$"
     ignoreCase="true" />
```

The `isFile="true"` flag, will only match urls that point to an existing file. `\.` in the pattern will match a dot.

---

More information:

- [URL Rewrite Module Configuration Reference](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference)
- [Apache Module mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html)